# How to prevent from mdk3 and netcut cutting my network

Tags: wireless-networking

There's a wifi network at my school it is really fast. i'm using it for doing my homework and doing exercise.
but , some of my friends trying to disconnect my network using a program called mdk3 on linux and netcut on windows.
it is really annoying because i can't do my homework and my exercise because of that.

is there anyway to prevent mdk3 and netcut disconnecting my network ?

sorry for my english if there's anything wrong. because english is not my native languange

Answer (score 1):

netcut/mdk3 is using a `deauth` packet to disconnect your session.  Unfortunately, this is part of the wireless standard, and cannot be disabled/ignored.

Your option is to report the deauths to the network administrators.  Their technical options are to change the authentication model to EAP-TLS, or to set up Management Frame Protection.  Neither are likely outcomes.

The real solution is probably to report the people in question and have the network administrators take appropriate action.

Comment: Hmm , So there is no a program like anti netcut or mdk3 to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

## Netcut :

there is no solution for the death packet but there is a solution for netcut as a program you can install netcut defender or install netcut itself and check "Protect this computer" in the program and you can install it from the site arcai .

## Mdk3 :

And for the mdk3 there is an indirect solution because it's different from netcut (netcut let you connected but there is no internet) but mkd3 disconnect you from the network so you can install linux via a virtual machine and use a usb wireless adapter or install linux as an operating system to use your computer wifi card ... =>**So**=> open two terminals in linux one to create new Access Point named "Stop_Jumming_And_I_Will_Stop" and the other to disconnect all the client from all the Accesses Point around you ... do that for 5 minute and the hackers around you will understand the story ... i'm always doing that in my universityand disconnect all of them :) :) so the first command is , 

**airmon-ng start wlan0 ; airbase-ng -e Stop_Jumming_And_I_Will_Stop -c 9 -v mon0** 
and the next one is 

**mdk3 mon0 d**
 mon0 is your interface and remember you can use the even if you are not connected to any network

Answer (score 0):

**MDK3**
IDK how to avoid this tool if u are using Windows OS..
But if use linux
just run

## airodump-ng mon0

and then u can see which MAC address capturing the biggest frames , in this case it is Attacker's MAC ..
just copy that mac

## macchanger -m "ATTACKER MAC"

BINGO ...
You're back ..
SO its just you and the attacker can connect to AP ..
hope this helpfull

## LORdA_18.02